# Redirecting modules controller to one specific controller in HMVC codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, authentication, hmvc

Making an offline app with codeigniter . The app is used for storing client data . I have used codeigniter hmvc approach . and now i have about eight modules in my app like templates , search, client , user etc ..user module checks for admin authentication . The number of modules will increase in the future .

Now to check if a user is logged in as admin i have used this piece of code in every module in __construct() function without templates and user modules because when i try to put this code in templates or users controller then firefox says `Page could not be redirected properly`

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_type')){
    redirect(base_url().'users/login');
}
```

Pasting this piece of code to templates and users module creates the problem . when i remove this code then everything works fine . as so user can still acess templates and user modules without login .

I just want to know that if there is any better way of doing it without pasting this piece of code in every controllers or making guest not to access any modules or method without login .

Comment: Update the question. Put some code of login function. I'll try to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you user HMVC than you can do it like this:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_type')){
    redirect('module_name/users/login'); // change module_name with your module name
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Maybe, You redirect on one page that redirect also... and put on loop

Comment: Check if everything is ok with the names of file, and paths, because I use it every day and it works. I always use HMVC and redirect in this way, and works.

Comment: Of course it works on the rest of the modules like a charm but . i am at my wit's end why it is not working for templates and users . by the way i have used templates modules in every modules ! ?

Comment: I use this CodeIgniter HMVC library. It works great, and it is very clear! http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/

Comment: `UPDATE: Maybe, You redirect on one page that redirect also... and put on loop` @ Erman Belegu . Hmm may be this is the prob ...

Comment: Check it, because you can put on loop the controller, and redirect on each-other. Check it again please, because the error says this!

Comment: made a quick fix by making a separate module just for login . :(

Comment: Finally Found the problem . Every controller in modules is calling templates modules and when i put redirect on those modules __construct() then it works fine but putting redirect code to templates __construct() makes redirect an endless loop. But in Hmvc there is no other way to protect the templates module rather than putting that code to each functions .

Comment: Nice, so problem was looping how I said. Nice to hear that you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified the complete site url, into redirect there is already the path without using `base_url()`
try this:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_type')){
    redirect('/users/login');
}
```

Comment: sorry but none of the redirect works ... i have tried many method . but pasting this piece of code to templates and users modules creating the problem

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: in other page you can works? I mean have you test other page or only this redirect doesn't work?

Comment: only on templates and users controller it doesn't work .. it works fine in the rest of the modules .

Comment: ok check name convention and try to put ini_set('display_errors',1); to see if something wrong @shahriar31